# Familienzusammenführung

Tags: visa, germany

Mein Mann studiert in Berlin und wir werden demnächst einen Antrag auf Familienzusammenführung stellen. Wir haben eine dreijährige Tochter. Da wir kein Haus finden konnten, haben wir einen unbefristeten Mietvertrag mit einem Hotel abgeschlossen, das Anmeldung anbietet. Ist der Mietvertrag mit dem Hotel akzeptabel?

> My husband is studying in Berlin and we will soon apply for family reunification. We have a three-year-old daughter. Since we could not find a house, we signed a permanent rental agreement with a hotel that offers registration. Is the rental agreement with the hotel acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

An unlimited time contract giving you an "Anmeldung" is already 2 out of 3. The third is the requirement of "ausreichender Wohnraum" (sufficient living space).

The exact square meter number may vary by federal state, you would have to look it up for your "Bundesland", but in general:

> A self-contained apartment with kitchen, bathroom and WC is always considered
> sufficient if:
>
> - twelve square meters for each person over the age of six are available
> - ten square meters for each person under six years of age are available.
> - Children under the age of 2 are not counted
> - The decisive factor is not the living space available for each person, but the size of the apartment including the adjoining rooms.
> - A shortfall of around 10 % in the size of this apartment is
>   harmless.

"harmless" is a rather weird translation for a weird German wording and means they will let it pass, if it is less than 10% off, because it would be too much hardship to make someone move for a square meter or two.

So it is 2 adults and a three year old kid. So you need to rent something that has a **kitchen**, **bathroom with a toilet** and (12+12+10 =) **34 square meters combined**. Anything between 31 and 34 might be acceptable, but legally you need 34.

That is not big, I kinda hope you rent something bigger, because in 34 square meters you will feel very boxed in with a three year old. But legally that's it.

Make sure you bring your rental agreement to the appointment. And maybe a "Kontoauszug" (account statement) showing you paid them at least once. The account statement maybe optional, but my rental agreement was so old it was typed on a typewriter and specified rent in DM, the currency we had before the EUR, so maybe it was only me. But maybe not. Just bring it, better to have it and not need it, than to have to make another appointment.

Comment: The hotel we have a contract with offers us an area of ​​42 square meters. The kitchen, bathroom and toilet are shared. The only question I'm curious about here is making a contract with a hotel. Is this situation acceptable?

Comment: When you say "shared", do you mean shared between your family, or shared between you and other guests? I can see that for a community kitchen, but what kind of hotel shares it's bathrooms between guests? Not having your own bathroom for your family would definetely something that is not okay. That is borderline acceptable for the cheapest youth hostel one can book for a one-week school trip, but not for living there long term. Especially with a kid.

Comment: The bathroom is shared between the family ie my wife, my daughter and me. The kitchen is shared with other guests.

Comment: Okay, shared between your family is not considered "shared". It's yours exclusively, so that is good. A community kitchen is something that the authorities *could* maybe accept, but don't have to. That is... a risk. German authorities are not known to be relaxed and forgiving with rules. On the other hand, 42 m² with a shared kitchen is perfectly fine for a German student couple, so maybe that would work in your favor... still, it's a risk. If you want to play it by the book and be safe, find a rental appartment for your family. Or maybe you can ask the authorities ahead of time if it is okay.